# Matlab exercise: i just don't get it

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Given the signals:

```
f1[n] = sinc[n] {1[n+5]-1[n-5]}
f2[n] = 1-rect[n]
f3[n] = 1[n]-1[n-5]
```

write a programm in matlab in which you will check the following proprieties:

```
1)sinc[n]:=sin(phi*n)/phi*n;
2)(f1*f2)[n] = (f2*f1)[n];
3)f1[n]*{ f2[n] + f3[n] } = f1[n]*f2[n] + f1[n]*f3[n];
4)(f1*delta)[n] = (delta*f1)[n] = f1[n];
```

I'm really really grateful for any tips/ideal on how to solve this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sinc[n]:=sin(phi*n)/phi*n;
```

That certainly isn't Matlab syntax, and the `;` at the end makes it not look much like a question either. Anyway, you have two options. Either plot the functions to visually assess equivalence or else check the vectors. I'll demonstrate with this one, then you can try for all the others.

Firstly you need to make a sample `n` vector which will be your domain over which to test equivalence (i.e. the x values of your plot). I'm going to arbitrarily choose:

```
n = -10:0.01:10;
```

Also I'm going to assuming by `phi` you actually meant `pi` based on the Matlab definition of `sinc`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html

So now we have to functions:

```
a = sinc(n);
b = sin(n)./n;
```

`a` and `b` are now vectors with a corresponding "y" value for each element of `n`. You'll also notice I used a `.` before the `/`, this means element wise divide i.e. divide each element by each corresponding element rather than matrix division which is inversion followed by matrix multiplication.

Now lets plot them:

```
plot(n, a, n, b, 'r')
```

and finally to check numerical equivalence we could do this:

```
all(a == b)
```

But (and this is probably a bit out of scope for your question but important to know) you should actually never check for absolute equivalence of floating point numbers like that as you get precision errors due to different truncations in the inner calculations (because of how your computer stores floating point numbers). So instead it is good practice to rather check that the difference between the two numbers is less than some tiny threshold.

```
all((a - b) < 0.000001)
```

I'll leave the rest up to you